# Oracle - Como gerar todos os dias (Calendário) entre duas Datas com Anos diferentes (*Sem Tabela de Apoio)

Tags: oracle

Como gerar o intervalo de todas as dias dos meses entre duas datas?

Considerando apenas os parâmetros:
Data Inicial: 10/01/2014
Data Final: 29/12/2018

Exemplo:

01/01/2014
02/01/2014
03/01/2014
...
26/12/2018
27/12/2018
28/12/2018
29/12/2018
30/12/2018
31/12/2018

Comment: Eu encontrei uma solução em:(https://sqlshow.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/calendario-em-sql-oracle/#comment-61) e alterei um pouco sugerindo melhorias!

Comment: @RovannLinhalis alguma sugestão, devo remover o artigo e comentar no outro? Dei uma olhada e são situações semelhantes, mas não há presença da pessoa no meu caso, apenas dois intervalos de data

Comment: não sei se é necessário remover esta, até porque serve como outro caminho para se chegar a um resultado, só achei válida a menção como duplicata porque a solução é praticamente a mesma.

Comment: Como o @RovannLinhalis cita a resposta é uma outra maneira, está relacionada com a outra pergunta, mas é de uso mais genérico, pois a resposta aqui pode ser aplicada em uma view por exemplo, enquanto que a outra pergunta usa conceitos avançados e tem uma tabela de relacionamento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os seguinte código pode ser usado:

```
SELECT
 CAL.DATA

,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'DD')) AS Dia

,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'MM')) AS Mes

,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'YY')) AS "AnoYY"

,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'YYYY')) AS "AnoYYYY"

,TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'day') AS "Descr_Dia"

,TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'dy') AS "Descr_Dia_abrev"

,TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'Month') AS "Descr_Mes"

,TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'Mon') AS "Descr_Mes_abrev"

,TO_CHAR(CAL.DATA,'dd month yyyy') AS Data_texto

FROM (
SELECT
  (
    TO_DATE(SEQ.MM || SEQ.YYYY, 'MM/YYYY')-1
    -- Subtrai 1 por SEQ.NUM não começar em zero
  ) + SEQ.NUM AS "DATA" 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT RESULT NUM, 
        TO_CHAR(( -- Data Mínima
            TO_DATE('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            ) , 'MM') AS "MM",
        TO_CHAR(( -- Data Mínima
            TO_DATE('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            ) , 'YYYY') AS "YYYY"
        FROM
          (
          SELECT ROWNUM RESULT FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (
                (
                -- Data Máxima
                LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('31/12/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
                -
                -- Data Mínima
                TRUNC(TO_DATE('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) -- Sempre primeiro dia do mês
                ) + 1 -- Último dia do último ano
            )
          ) -- Quantas sequências para gerar pelo MAX

    ) SEQ
) CAL
;
```